# Question re "ese"

Tags: coloquialismos

I have an editing question. I've read the answers to a question here from a few years ago on "ese" and understand it's slang that originated in Mexico City, used in Chicano dialect. My question comes from an author having the word (spelled "esse") used by a Puerto Rican character, c. 2008. Would someone from Puerto Rico typically have that word in her vocabulary? Thanks.

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/what-does-ese-mean)?

Comment: It is used by Mexicans, not only chicanos.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you may have seen it spelled as **"Esse"** is perhaps onomatopoeic, as the /s/ in "ese" is often spoken as a longer hissing sound, but this is very community specific.

Although the dictionary definition cited here another answer is precise and correct, A bit of history may be in order to clarify the meaning and the reason it is sometimes spelled as **"Esse"**.

**"Ese"** is a shorthand for a longer slang **"Ese vato loco"** (roughly  *yo', trippy dude*) among chicanos and latin american gangs of all origins, and as far back as the 50's [Zoot Suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoot_suit) chicanos in East Los Angeles.

Thus, *"Ese"* is idiomatically translated as *"Yo"* and used in the same manner

Examples:

- Estas bien loco, ese (*You're mad crazy**, 'yo*)
- Hey, Caele a mi canton, ese; hay fiesta, loco (*hey, drop over my pad 'Yo, im throwing a party, fool*)
- Con mi morrita no te metas, ese! (*Leave my girl alone, 'Yo*)

In the northern state of Baja California, Mexico, Tijuana Gangs use to greet their members with a formulaic **"quihubo, ese bato loco, rifa la trece"** alluding to their neighborhood gang (roughly:*'sup 'yo, trippy dude, 13 rules here*** this is actually common and current use in this neck of the woods.

---

***: "Loco"** in this context means being High on some substance

****:** *13 / thirteen* is a common slang for *"local gang"* or a reference to *Mara Salvatrucha or MS13* Salvadorean gangs, after which many local gangs model themselves in fashion and attitude.

Comment: ese can be *man, too*. Estás bien loco, ese. You're really crazy, man.

Answer (score 1):

ese, -a.
I.  1.  m. y f. EU. **Hombre o mujer. pop.**

[Diccionario de americanismos](https://www.asale.org/damer/ese)

Comment: Por desgracia, que una palabra [no] esté en el diccionario no garantiza que *would someone from Puerto Rico typically have that word in her vocabulary* 

Comment: @tac Dice diccionario de *americanismos*.

Comment: I know what it means -- I'm curious whether someone from Puerto Rico would typically use the word. Would a Spanish-speaking Puerto Rican use Chicano slang? Is the word "ese" widespread among Spanish-speaking people who are not Chicano or Mexican?

Comment: Sé lo que significa. Tengo curiosidad por saber si alguien de Puerto Rico normalmente usaría la palabra. ¿Un puertorriqueño hispanohablante usaría jerga chicana? ¿Está muy extendida la palabra "ese" entre los hispanohablantes que no son chicanos ni mexicanos?

Comment: @Lambie Que puedas encontrar algo en el diccionario de americanismos no te garantiza que ‘tengas calle’. Sí, si es por eso entonces también [mariconear](https://www.asale.org/damer/mariconear) aparece pero, al menos acá, esa palabra está algo pasada de moda y difícilmente se escuche

Comment: Sé solo que los mexicanos lo utilizan.

Comment: Me fui al supermercado y hablé con un puertorriqueño que me dijo que no. No se dice en PR.

Comment: Thank you! I'll tell my author.